# thymeleaf dependency in springboot not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm starting with a project in springboot, and I've an error that I've never seen before and I have not been able to solve it, it is with the thymeleaf dependency is not working, im working with intellij idea community edition. it dont let me use the th:text, please see the image. i have deleted the project and redownloaded several times, delete the m2 folder and nothing works for me.

this is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

@GetMapping(value = "/index")
public String index(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("titulo", "nombre");
    return "index";
}
}
```

this is de index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>th:text="${titulo}"</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

when i run the code localhost don't show me the correct information, I already have the dependency installed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57CoA.png)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8fqX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template is being served as a static resource. The controller has a mapping for `/index` but you have accessed `http://localhost:8080`. Either change the mapping to `@GetMapping("/")` or access `http://local host:8080/index`. You should also check the location of `index.html` in your project. It should be in `src/main/resources/templates`.